# How can i Lifting x86_64 assembly code to LLVM-IR

Tags: malware, obfuscation, deobfuscation, virtual-machines, llvm

I'm researching of virus and I'm faced with the task of deobfuscating its virtual machine. I chose to do this through LLVM and I had a question, where can I see a simple example of lifting instructions to the LLVM-IR level? For example, where can I look at code that just translate one pop rsp instruction to LLVM-IR? Since I didn't find anything like that.

Maybe someone has articles where this is described or can someone suggest with an example?

Comment: I think I used [RetDec](https://github.com/avast/retdec) to lift PE to LLVM IR

Comment: @raspiduino I am studying for a PhD (Computer Science) and this is my project, a 500 megabyte file, also cannot process retdec. I need to make my own code lifter, can you tell me with this?